# getting url of child window when it is redirected, from parent window(facebook oAuth generation)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on facebook integration from a closed application, facebook has given a way to get authentication code by hitting the url

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

When we hit this url facebook login window comes on screen, after logging in facebook redirects to the url `{facebook_domain}/connect/login_success.html?code=XXXXXX_=_`

i need this `code` in the url in my parent window or java code so I can further process it.

Approach I was thinking was to open above facebook link in a child window, using `window.open` or `iframe` and get the redirected url of the child window in the parent window but I was not able to get redirected url of the child window in parent window.

I cannot think of any other approach. For facebook oAuth code generation You can check facebook developer docs(Manually Build a Login Flow).

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom open window function as follows to keep a track of all the open child windows in your parent page and launch a timeout event to close the child after some reasonable time fetching the child object and then getting its href. I havent tested it but should give you an idea where to look into.

```
//assuming there is only one child window
var childWindow;
var windowsOpened = [];

function openChildWindow(url,name,params){
   windowsOpened.push(window.open(url,name,params));
   triggerTimeout(windowsOpened[0]);
   return windowsOpened[0];
}

function triggerTimeout(win){
   setTimeout(function(){ childWindow = win;},10);
}

function getUrlOfChild(){
   if(childWindow){
     alert(childWindow.location);
     childWindow.close();
   }
}
```

Make sure to run it on a server and test it and not directly as file://test.html. Otherwise it will throw js protocol errors